# How to sort data in an asp.net gridview by properties of sub-objects?

Tags: asp.net, .net, sorting, gridview

I have a `List<Role>` (see below) that I am binding to an [asp.net gridview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview(v=vs.110).aspx). I want to sort this data using [`SortExpression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sortexpression(v=vs.110).aspx), such that it is sorted by two properties *of sub-objects* of the rows. Specifically, I want to sort by the `Application`'s `Name`, then the `ApplicationType`'s `ApplicationTypeName`.

How can I do this?

The classes here are:

```
public class Application
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Status {get; set;}
}

public class ApplicationType
{
    public string ApplicationTypeName {get; set;}
    public int ApplicationTypeStatus {get; set;}
}

public class Role
{
    public Application oApplication {get; set;}
    public ApplicationType oApplicationType {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: I realise this is your first stackoverflow question, but you *might* want to think a bit more about: "what information would the reader need to answer my question?" - for example, it seems the *actual* question is about asp.net gridview, which isn't even hinted at in the question; additionally the question title says "array", the example says `List<T>`, and the tags say "arraylist" - these  3 things are **completely different and mutually exclusive**. The tags also say "linq", which isn't evident anywhere else... We're happy to help, but we aren't psychic. I will edit to illustrate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: note that I was responding to the [*earlier verison of the question*](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26337870/3), before it related to gridview; still, this might be useful...

Worst case: you can use the approach here to pre-sort the list before binding it to the gridview.

---

Various options:

- implement `IComparable[<T>]`
- implement `IComparer[<T>]`
- use an  ad-hoc sort

I'm guessing you just need the last, so perhaps:

```
list.Sort((x,y) => {
    int delta = string.Compare(x.Application.Name, y.Application.Name);
    if (delta == 0) delta = string.Compare(
        x.ApplicationType.ApplicationTypeName, y.ApplicationType.ApplicationTypeName);
    return delta;
});
```

Alternatively, you can perhaps do it via LINQ in the source data - note however that this is done when creating a *new* list - it isn't an in-place sort of an *existing* list:

```
var list = source.OrderBy(x => x.Application.Name)
                 .ThenBy(x => x.ApplicationType.ApplicationTypeName)
                 .ToList();
```

Comment: Marc Gravell :: thanks for answer : this list to be bonded to Gridview so when i want to sort by Application the sortExpresion will be "Application.Name" how this will be done ?

Comment: @user2516342 back up a moment; you haven't even told me what UI implementation you are using; the question doesn't say anything about `Gridview`, etc; where are you using/seeing `sortExpression`?

Comment: :: My mistake i am using asp.net GridView to bind List<Role> in it And some column view property in class Application.Name or ApplicationType.Name.

Comment: @user2516342 I don't know whether Gridview supports sorting by properties of sub-objects

Comment: :: the sorting is custom so nothing to do with GridView

Comment: @nabukhas if you are trying to sort via `SortExpression`, it has *everything* to do with gridview...

Comment: Thank you Marc Gravell the following [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366332/best-way-to-get-sub-properties-using-getproperty) solve my problem.