# Get Property of object by nested property string

Tags: c#

I have different **objects** like: `CallingItem`, `TransferItem` or `FlowItem` and I have an appropriated **String** containing the needed property of the object e.g. `Message.Start.MsgNumber` or `Data.Name`

Examples of my objects with property:

```
TransferItem.Message.Start.MsgNumber = 5;
CallingItem.Data.Name = "Mike"
```

Method call:

```
GetProperty(TransferItem, "Message.Start.MsgNumber");
GetProperty(CallingItem, "Data.Name");
```

Method GetProperty:

```
public void GetProperty(object myObject, string propertyString)
{
    Type t = myObject.GetType();

    PropertyInfo pinfo = t.GetProperty(propertyString);

    if (pinfo == null)
        return;

    object value = pinfo.GetValue(null, null);
}
```

But pinfo is always null. How can I get the property value of  my object?

Comment: Why do you work with strings at all?

Comment: `GetProperty` does not support nesting properties like "Foo.Bar".

Comment: You need some recursive method that returns just a single part of your path instead of the entire structure.

Comment: In addition to the dupe, you can also look here for jonskeet answer:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366332/best-way-to-get-sub-properties-using-getproperty